# How to parse context relevant log file in Racket?

Tags: racket

I try parse a log file using Racket by reading the log file line by line as follows

```
(define (read-next-line-iter file)
  (let ((line (read-line file)))
    (unless (eof-object? line)
      (filter-log line)
      (read-next-line-iter file))))

(define (filter-log line)
  (match line
    [(regexp #rx"errCode *:") (display line)]
    [_ (void)]))

(call-with-input-file "lines2read.log" read-next-line-iter)
```

However, in some of the match cases, there's context relevant. Some contents of the log file would be

```
[I][2014-12-11 +8.0 10:24:50.150][3518, 127][OnGYNetEnd][, , 0][onGYNetEnd after post to worker netId:0, errType:0, errCode:0, isCancel:false, hashcode:1130102720
[I][2014-12-11 +8.0 10:24:50.150][3518, 127][OnGYNetEnd][, , 0][blabla, this line not important]
[I][2014-12-11 +8.0 10:38:12.743][3518, 127][APAuth][, , 0][onGYNetEnd : errType : 4, errCode : -100, errMsg : hit push hold!!
[I][2014-12-11 +8.0 10:38:12.743][3518, 127][APAuth][, , 0][THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT, WE NEED TO GRAP IT!
[I][2014-12-11 +8.0 10:38:12.743][3518, 127][APAuth][, , 0][THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT TOO, WE NEED TO GRAP IT!
```

Take the log file above for instance:

- If the `errCode` is `0`, and the next line does not match the `regexp` cases, **ignore** it.
- If the `errCode` is **NOT** `0`, Even the next 2 lines does not match the `regexp` cases, **print** it.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to encode your "state" as an explicit value. So, for instance, it sounds like you need to know

- did the prior line have error code zero?
- did one of the two prior lines have a nonzero error code?

it looks like it would be sufficient here to keep track of the previous two error codes; I would add this as an explicit argument to your `read-next-line-iter` function. You'll have to think about what they should be at the start of the file.